# Idle3 editor fail to open in Fedora 36

Tags: python

I am currently unable to open Idle3 editor. I am running Linux Fedora 36, when idle3 command is issued I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/idle3", line 3, in <module> from idlelib.pyshell import main
File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 53, in <module> from idlelib import debugger
File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/idlelib/debugger.py", line 7, in <module> from idlelib     import macosx
File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/idlelib/macosx.py", line 7, in <module> from test.support import requires, ResourceDenied
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test'
```

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I sniffed code /usr/lib64/python3.10/idlelib and really there is no test module. Packaging error?

Comment: AFIK the truuble comes from Fedora packaging, apparently some files were forgoten. So the new question is how can I add such a file?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunatelly the trouble with Idle3 was solved in the recent update of Fedora 36, I think the missing file was inserted.